# About gulp task dependences

Tags: gulp

I write `gulpfile.js` like:

```
...

gulp.task('styles',function(){
  gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(concat('tmp.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
    .pipe(notify('Styles task complete'))
})

gulp.task('css',['styles'],function(cb){
  del(['./build/css/tmp.css'],cb)
})
.....
```

When I run `gulp css`,the `styles` task will first be execute, so  `./build/css/tmp.css` will be removed.

But the `./build/css/tmp.css` is still exist.That is mean,when the `css` task be executed,the `styles` task has not yet be execute.

Why the dependences not work? and how can I make sure the `'./build/css/tmp.css'` has exist before the `css` task be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue intermittently working without the returns in dependencies.

You need to return the actual task so gulp knows when it's complete.

So this should become :

```
gulp.task('styles',function(){
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(concat('tmp.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
    .pipe(notify('Styles task complete'))
});

gulp.task('css',['styles'],function(cb){
  del(['./build/css/tmp.css'],cb)
})
```

This will then wait for styles to complete (as a dependency returned) and then continue.